# About dynamic array construction in C++

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm revising my C++ skills for a machine learning project. So, I was working on a dynamically allocating memory functionality. My idea is define such functions as static ones and put them  a class and then call them as needed. So I defined following headerfile named Utils.h -

```
//Utils.h
#include <stdio.h>

class Utils
{
public:
    template<class T> static T* create1DArray(int size);            
};
```

Then I created following Utils.cpp as -

```
//Utils.cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include"Utils.h"


template<class T> T* Utils::create1DArray(int size)
{
    T* a = new T [size];
    return a;
}
```

Then I tested them as -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include"Utils.cpp"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Test";
    double* a;    
    int n=3;
    a = Utils.create1DArray<double>(n);
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

But I got following errors -

```
error C2275: 'Utils' : illegal use of this type as an expression    
error C2228: left of '.create1DArray' must have class/struct/union  
error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
```

But surprisingly when I use this function as a standalone one without putting inside the function it works. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Sorry, I meant: use the `::` scope operator to access a static member of a class, not the `.` dot operator which is reserved for accessing a non-static member.

Comment: These aren't technically dynamic arrays, simply dynamically allocated arrays. A dynamic array will gain/lose in size depending on content.

Comment: thanx Luc a lot, I forgot this syntax....been working for 3 hours; I seriously need some rest now...!

Comment: If you look at the error you see _left of '.create1DArray' must have class/struct/union_ and actually `Utils` is not any of them since it's a class declaration

Comment: If you put the definition of the function in a .cpp file, you will get a link error after you correcting your syntax error.

Comment: Probably you also want a namespace instead of a class.

Comment: Guys, I was trying to use the . dot notation to invoke a static method instead of :: That was the only mistake...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `.` dot notation to invoke a static method.

Use the `::` correct operator instead.

```
Utils::create1DArray<double>(n)
```

Comment: You can actually use the `.` operator to invoke a static member function if the left hand side is an object, e.g. `Utils u; u.create1DArray<double>(n);`.